# ImportXML from ESPN.com "Imported content is empty"

Tags: html, import

I am attempting to import Major League Baseball data from the main table on [this](http://espn.go.com/mlb/probables) page using the =ImportXML function on Google Sheets. I would like to import only the rows which contain the name of the starting pitcher in the first column (the grey rows). I am currently using the following function:

=IMPORTXML("http://espn.go.com/mlb/probables", "//tr[@class='oddrow']/td | //tr[@class='evenrow']/td")

I keep receiving the "imported content is empty" error. Do you see what I am doing incorrectly in my function?

Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to import to Google-Sheets then why does this question have the `excel` technical tag? Throwing mud at a wall to see what sticks only serves to obfuscate the question at hand.

Comment: I deleted the excel tag... thanks for the recommendation. I added it because Stack Overflow would not allow me to add a Google Sheets tag, so I thought Excel was similar enough. I guess not :). Can anyone answer my question though? I really need some help on this.

Comment: Just found another website which I can use... for others, I found a post saying that the ESPN stats are not able to be imported through importxml. Possibly incorrect, but I could not get it to work.